# Разрешить скачивать файл только раз в сутки

Tags: php

есть ли функция или пример как запретить скачивать файл по ип и логину больше 1 раза в сутки? В бд хранятся логи всех скачиваний каждого пользователя. В поиске искал, подобных функций не нашел.

Comment: Это все понятно, но очень интересен данный вопрос.

Comment: Просто функционал экзотичный и маловостребованный. Так что стандартной реализации вряд ли найдёшь. По сути - сильно похоже на то, что организуют некоторые файлопомойки, генеря каждому клиенту уникальный ссыль на файл. Но это же надо отдавать файл через скрипт... кстати, скрипт ведь может фиксировать, что именно загружено, блокировать многопоточности, и вообще - но зато ресурсы жрёт как не в себя.

Comment: А файл скачивается сквозь php скрипт ? Если да, то собственно делаете запрос в БД, были ли сегодня обращения и если да, то не отдаете. так что никаких специализированных функций нет и поэтому вы их не находите